# WHAT DOES (file_t)(-1),0, IN THE STRUCTURE MEAN?

Tags: c, linux, sdk

I am making changes in a atheros SDK for my need and wish to understand why and for what purpose (file_t)(-1), 0, is used in the structure:

```
  struct channel channel =
{
        (file_t)(-1),
        0,
        CHANNEL_ETHNUMBER,
        CHANNEL_ETHDEVICE,
        {
                0x00,
                0xB0,
                0x52,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x01
        },
        {
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00,
                0x00
        },
        0x0000,

#if defined (__linux__)

#elif defined (__APPLE__) || defined (__OpenBSD__)

        0,
        0,
        0,
        0,

#elif defined (WINPCAP) || defined (LIBPCAP)
        (pcap_t *)(0),
        {
                0
        },

#else
#error "Unknown Environment"
#endif

        CHANNEL_TIMEOUT,
        CHANNEL_OPTIONS
};
```

I am not exploring the SDK and would help if anyone suggest to start off.
Thanking you.

Comment: What is `struct channel`? What is its first member?.... So... Unclear....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have presented the declaration of variable `channel` as a struct of type `struct channel`.  The code you asked about is in this variable's initializer:

```
    (file_t)(-1),
    0,
```

These are the values with which to initialize the first two members of `channel`.  The first is `-1`, cast to type `file_t` (which must have been defined earlier), and the second is itself.

The *meaning* of those members depends on the details of `struct channel` and the way it is used, which you have not provided.